# How pass XML file to the method?

Tags: c#, xml, service

I have a method in service that has this signature:

public string submitInvoice(string username, string password, string inXML)

I created XML in my C# code like this:

```
   protected XmlDocument generateXML()
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode xmlnode = xmldoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration, "", "");
        xmldoc.AppendChild(xmlnode);
        //root element
        XmlElement xmlelem = xmldoc.CreateElement("", "Invoices", "");
        xmldoc.AppendChild(xmlelem);



        //(child of the root)
        XmlElement xmlelem2 = xmldoc.CreateElement("", "InvoiceNumber", "");
        XmlText xmltext = xmldoc.CreateTextNode("222222");
        xmlelem2.AppendChild(xmltext);
        xmldoc.ChildNodes.Item(1).AppendChild(xmlelem2);



        return xmldoc;

    }
```

in my program I have:

XmlDocument xml = generateXML();

and then call that method:

oResponse = oWscape.submitInvoice(sUserName, sPassword, *****);
 I am not sure what should I send as inXML, it is type string but when I try string it gave me an error. How I can send an XML here?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @nik Are you sure the signature of `submitInvoice()` is what you think it is? Also, you should edit clarifying information into your question instead of scattering it through comments. Also, for error messages, point out with a comment where in your code sample they occur. (Since the line numbers probably don't match.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the XML as a string via the document element's OuterXml property, as in:

```
submitInvoice("username", "password", xml.DocumentElement.OuterXml);
```

Comment: Actually, you should also be OK with `xml.OuterXml`.  The difference being that `xml.OuterXml` gives you the markup for whatever node xml is currently referencing, while `xml.DocumentElement.OuterXml` is explicitly the root node.

Comment: I get this error when I use this: cannot implicitly convert type string to 'system.xml.xmlnode'

Comment: Sounds like you're passing it as `submitInvoice("username", "password", xml)`.  The `xml` variable in your sample is declared as type XmlDocument (derived from XmlNode).  The `OuterXml` property is of type `string`, which is what your `submitInvoice` method is expecting.

Comment: I used it as: submitInvoice("username", "password", xml.DocumentElement.OuterXml);  OR   oResponse = oWinscape.submitInvoice(sUserName, sPassword, xml.OuterXml); both give me same error:  cannot implicitly convert type string to 'system.xml.xmlnode'

Comment: Aha!  I missed it in your earlier comment.  "cannot implicitly convert type **string** to **'system.xml.xmlnode'**"  That error is about an attempt to convert **to** XML.  (Whereas the original problem was trying to pass XML as string.)  Your declaration for `submitInvoice()` returns string, I'm going to guess `oResponse` is declared as XmlNode.

Comment: OK, so change oResponse to string.  Voila! You now have a string containing the result of your call to `submitInvoice()`.  If that string is itself a blob of XML, you then have the option of loading it into another XmlDocument object via the `LoadXml()` method.  The part you may be missing is that an "XML Document" can be treated as a string; the XmlDocument class on the other hand provides a object representation of such a document with properties and methods that make it easier to work with.  It's possible to convert between the two, but they aren't exactly the same thing.